# How to send fetch('%URL%') in Scrapy after getting banned by the website?

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get into web scraping and I got banned by the website. Now when I open its main page it says "Sorry, you’re not allowed to access this page" and throws Error 503 in Scrapy.

I know that I should be able to create an object and put proxies in its meta settings, but I just can't do that right. Could you show me how to do this or maybe point in the right direction?

Also, when I type fetch('request') where "request" is an object I've tried creating, I get the same 503 error as it tries to fetch not the URL I specified but the previous one I fetched.

I know that might sound like a noob question and that's because it is a noob question. I tried looking here before asking but couldn't find the answer (or maybe I choose the wrong search query).

Answer (score 0):

`req = uRequest(itemurl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`
Try to add headers somewhere where you made a request

Comment: I think it's an IP ban because I can't access the website from my phone. I already changed my UA and referer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [requests-tor](https://pypi.org/project/requests-tor/) package to send requests through tor.
from the docs:

```
from requests_tor import RequestsTor
rt = RequestsTor() #for Tor Browser
rt = RequestsTor(tor_ports=(9050,), tor_cport=9051) #for Tor

url = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
r = rt.get(url)
print(r.text)
```